# Cannot replace some html characters with str_replace()

Tags: php, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

From the database I receive the following text:

```
&lt;div onclick=&quot;alert('cÃ³digo inyectado');&quot;&gt;Texto&lt;/div&gt;

[img]http://www.hobbyconsolas.com/sites/hobbyconsolas.com/public/media/image/2015/07/503196-halo-5-guardians-nuevos-datos-campana-cooperativa.jpg[/img]

Y aquÃ­ una URL: [url]https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl[/url]

Bueno pues vamos [b]a ver si esto funciona[/b] porque &quot;todavÃ­a&quot; no lo sÃ© [i][u]bien[/u][/i]
```

This text is stored in a variable called `$texto`. Once `htmlspecialchars()` applied to the variable, I go through where I´m finding the problem:

```
$texto = str_replace("&quot;","\"",$texto); //para comillas
$texto = str_replace("&lt;","<",$texto); // para <
$texto = str_replace("&gt;",">",$texto); // para >
```

But no modification is done. If I remove the character `&` works, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: `htmlspecialcharacters()` isn't a native php function.  Show us what you are really doing at that point.

Comment: It sounds like you're double encoding, use `htmlspecialchars($texto, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @fyrye worked!!! I have tried with some html special characters and seems to work fine with all of them. Answer the question above so that I can validate. Thanks!

Comment: @EgoiCanteroViqueira added answer as requested

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't do that `htmlspecialchars()` call, and only call `str_replace()` once:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3c63925544ed8689825d5f731e7933faae086f6))

```
$texto="&lt;div onclick=&quot;alert('cÃ³digo inyectado');&quot;&gt;Texto&lt;/div&gt;

[img]http://www.hobbyconsolas.com/sites/hobbyconsolas.com/public/media/image/2015/07/503196-halo-5-guardians-nuevos-datos-campana-cooperativa.jpg[/img]

Y aquÃ­ una URL: [url]https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl[/url]

Bueno pues vamos [b]a ver si esto funciona[/b] porque &quot;todavÃ­a&quot; no lo sÃ© [i][u]bien[/u][/i]";
//$texto=htmlspecialchars($texto);

$texto = str_replace(["&quot;","&lt;","&gt;"],['"','<','>'],$texto);

var_export($texto);
```

Output:

```
'<div onclick="alert(\'cÃ³digo inyectado\');">Texto</div>

[img]http://www.hobbyconsolas.com/sites/hobbyconsolas.com/public/media/image/2015/07/503196-halo-5-guardians-nuevos-datos-campana-cooperativa.jpg[/img]

Y aquÃ­ una URL: [url]https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl[/url]

Bueno pues vamos [b]a ver si esto funciona[/b] porque "todavÃ­a" no lo sÃ© [i][u]bien[/u][/i]'
```

---

fyrye's suggestion yields this -- if this is what you are shooting for:

```
'<div onclick="alert(&#039;cÃ³digo inyectado&#039;);">Texto</div>

[img]http://www.hobbyconsolas.com/sites/hobbyconsolas.com/public/media/image/2015/07/503196-halo-5-guardians-nuevos-datos-campana-cooperativa.jpg[/img]

Y aquÃ­ una URL: [url]https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl[/url]

Bueno pues vamos [b]a ver si esto funciona[/b] porque "todavÃ­a" no lo sÃ© [i][u]bien[/u][/i]'
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're double encoding. To avoid the double encoding you can use.

```
htmlspecialchars($texto, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php